# Dialogue cleaning, Tron

Tags: noise, dialogue, reduction

Hi guys,
I was watching the Tron Legacy sound panel and Ms Whittle(sound supervisor)  mentions a specific software or hardware (i think its called nova) that they used to clean up the dialog eliminating a specific whine that the suit's lights generated [link text](http://soundworkscollection.com/tronlegacysoundshow)

Its around 16:25. Could anyone help out?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 2):

I beleive they're referring to Algorithmix reNOVAtor.

http://www.avid.com/US/products/reNOVAtor

http://www.algorithmix.com/en/renovator.htm

Comment: if it is reNOVAtor the results are pretty amazing, though I'm sure there was lots of painstaking work that had to be done on each sonic moment of that whine throughout.  

Its seems like similar results could be achieved through izotope rx2


Comment: Thank you guys for your asnwer. It's amazing results that they achieved, specially with such a low level dialogue. 